# Writing Configurable Step Functions

Tags: python, django

Assume I have 3 different charge schedules for a room for 3 types of memberships:

**Normal**

0 - 1 hours: $10 per hour

1 - 5 hours: $9 per hour

5 - 12 hours: $8 per hour

**Member**

0 - 1 hours: $8 per hour

1 - 5 hours: $7 per hour

5 - 12 hours: $6 per hour

**Premium**

0 - 1 hours: $4 per hour

1 - 5 hours: $3 per hour

5 - 12 hours: $2 per hour

These are charges that can be configurable at the front end.

What are best practises to store them dynamically and perform the calculation?

I have an idea but I believe there are better ones out there:

SQL Table: `membership_rates`

```
membership,min_hr,max_hr,rate
normal,0,1,10
normal,1,5,9
normal,5,12,8
member,0,1,8
member,1,5,7
member,5,12,6
premium,0,1,4
premium,1,5,3
premium,5,12,2
```

Then in the psuedo code,

```
find out membership type
query the rates for the membership type in an array

while rent_amt is larger than max_hr of the query:
  rate = selected_rate from the bracket
  find next smaller rate


return the rate * the no. of hours used
```

An example in Python (Django) is:

```
amt_used = rent.amt_used
membership = member.membership
rates = Rates.objects.filter(membership=membership).order_by(max_rate)
rate = 0
while amt_used > rates.max_hr:
    rate = rates.rate

return amt_used * rate
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically stored"? These value may change often?

Comment: yes the values can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your values in a variable :

```
CHARGES_SCHEDULES = {"normal" : {0 : {"time" : 1,
                                      "per_hour" : 10},
                                 {1 : {"time" : 5,
                                       "per_hour" : 9}},
                                 {5 : {"time" : 12,
                                       "per_hour" : 8}},},
                     "member" : {0 : {"time" : 1,
                                      "per_hour" : 8},
                                 {1 : {"time" : 5,
                                       "per_hour" : 7}},
                                 {5 : {"time" : 12,
                                       "per_hour" : 6}},},
                     "premium" : {0 : {"time" : 1,
                                       "per_hour" : 4},
                                 {1 : {"time" : 5,
                                       "per_hour" : 3}},
                                 {5 : {"time" : 12,
                                       "per_hour" : 2}},}}
```

(You can change the variable structure, of course. I used dictionnaries here but you can use tuples, lists or anything that may fit your needs better.)

Then you can either putting it directly in your **settings.py** or in a different python file (**charges.py** for instance) and import it in  your **settings.py**.

**1. Solution 1:**

Put it directly in your **settings.py** and then simply import your values in your python files when needed :

**anyfile.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings

print(settings.CHARGES_SCHEDULES["member"][1]["time"])
```

**2. Solution 2:**

Put it in a separate python file (e.g: **charges.py**) and import this file in your **settings.py** :

**settings.py**:

```
from charges import CHARGES_SCHEDULES
```

and then just import it in your other python files like previously (cf. Solution 1).